# MySQL: Explicit Hostname Vs Hostname with wildcard

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL treat an explicit hostname the same as a hostname with a wild card? For example, I have created a user via the following:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'iga'@'ip-10-11-2-150.aws.example.hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'SOMEPASSWORD';
```

Now, I want to grant the user permissions. Could I do it like the following, where the wildcard resolves any user from an ip-10-11-2-anything address?

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT ON iga.* TO 'iga'@'ip-10-11-2-%';
```

Or, do I have to explicitly put the same hostname as the user is created with, like the following:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT ON iga.* TO 'iga'@'ip-10-11-2-150.aws.example.hostname';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two distinct users.  If we run this statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON iga.* TO 'iga'@'ip-10-11-%'
```

Then MySQL will attempt to create a new user

```
'iga'@'ip-10-11-%'
```

This user is separate and distinct from the user created with the `CREATE USER` statement:

```
'iga'@'ip-10-11-2-150.aws.example.hostname'
```

which does *not* get the SELECT privilege. To give privileges to that user, We would need to give the full name that user in a `GRANT` statement:

```
 GRANT SELECT ON iga.* TO 'iga'@'ip-10-11-2-150.aws.example.hostname'
```

---

When a session connects to MySQL, it matches *one* row in the mysql.user table; it will find an exact match if it exists, otherwise, it may find a wildcard match. But once it matches a user, that's the *only* user it matches. The session gets only the privileges associated with the one user, not privileges granted to other users that would also be wildcard matches.

Comment: Thank you, you answered both the question I asked and the question I SHOULD have asked, which is whether MySQl treats the two users separately.